# Android community vs Anko Layouts

Tags: java, android, kotlin, anko, anko-component

I am confused about Anko Layout I read many advantages that Anko Layout have. One of them is executed much faster than xml. But my questions are:

- Is Anko Layout stable ?
- Is the community level the same as the Android Community?
- Have Anko any disadvantage or should continue with xml?

Answer (score 0):

I like Anko Layouts and use it for my personal project. The library seems to have been set aside and the community is very small. It is hard to recommend for a serious project unless you can afford to maintain your own fork of the Anko library (which might not be all that hard?)